# regex to get the most occurred value on a string (you don't know the value) in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, expression

I have a list of IPs in a text document, I use `File.open` or `File.readline` to keep inside a string and I have to build a Regex to get the most occurred IP in the list.

This is what I have so far:

```
file = File.open("/Users/leonardoeiki/workspace/foo.txt", "r") 
ips = Array.new 
file.each_line do |line| 
  array = line.match("some regex that return the ips") 
end 
# some code that return me the most occurred ip on the 
# array file = File.read("/Users/leonardoeiki/workspace/foo.txt")
```

There are other values in the archive like hours, alerts and errors messages, but I only need to return the most occurred ip

Comment: can you give us some sample input and expected output?

Comment: file = File.open("/Users/leonardoeiki/workspace/foo.txt", "r")  

ips = Array.new

file.each_line do |line| 

  array = line.match("some regex that return the ips")

end 

#some code that return me the most occurred ip on the array 

file = File.read("/Users/leonardoeiki/workspace/foo.txt")

#some code to return the most occurred ip

obs: that are other values in the archive like hours, alerts and errors messages, but i only need to return the most occurred ip

Comment: I recommend to ident in a text editor

Comment: Show us the file contents

Comment: it has 50 MB, its to big, thats why I am puting in a variable and asking to return only the values that I'm interested in

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: oh thanks, just started using this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the following text file

```
#file.txt

some text 192.168.1.1 some more text
some text 108.302.22.108 some more text
some text 108.302.22.108 some more text
```

Your ruby code should work with this

```
ips = File.readlines("file.txt").map do |line|
  line.scan(/\d{1,}\b/).join('.')
end

ips.map{|ip| {ip: ip, count: ips.select{|i| i == ip }.count}}.max_by{|h| h[:count]}

#=> {:ip=>"108.302.22.108", :count=>2}
```

Comment: it is not returning the most occurred ip

Comment: can you post example of your input data or subset of it?

Comment: I updated my answer, should work correctly now